# How to get element in 2d Java ArrayList?

Tags: java, json, arraylist

I have converted a json string into a java arraylist and I'm looking to access a specific element.

.get(0).get(2) for example doesn't work as I found on another question.

When I use .get(0) I get the following reposnse:

> [{ID=d224fe6b2d35728bbb9c9132db015ba0, Name=dl, DisplayName=Sneakers,
>   MatchTypes=[object], Score=1.0,
>   PassParams=reqID=MjAxOC0wMy0wMSAxNTowNTo0MS40NTcwNzM4MTMgKzAwMDAgVVRDIG09Kzc2MzIwNi45ODYzODkxNDZfXzA0MTgyMWEyNDg5MjZhNTZiLTYwYjBjNzA0ZDQ0NF9KaWtLTQ==}

So it looks like the arraylist is a list of lists.

I'm looking to access the DisplayName value

The only code I have has been to convert the json string and the attempt at accesing arraylist:

```
public void setJson(String jsonString) {

         Gson googleJson = new Gson();
         ArrayList array = googleJson.fromJson(jsonString, ArrayList.class);     

         String keyword = array.get(0).get(2).toString();
    }
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Show us the code you have so far, and what you've currently tried

Answer (score 0):

nested for loops to exhausted search is the easiest way for beginners; for example

```
for (int I = 0; I < array.length; I++)
{
     for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++)
     {
     }
}
```

then do an if else statement to return the statement you want; and give you the location.